# Is there a way to update from Adobe Air (flash) android app to a Unity3d app and keep the local save that is in shared object?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, flash, air

**This is the situation:** We have an android game that has been published for a few years now, that was originally developed in **ActionScript3** and built with **Adobe Air**...

Now, the problem we are facing is that because ActionScript3 is basically unsupported by most advertising and analytics SDKs, we need to update to something newer, without losing our current playerbase. So we started developing a clone of the current game in **Unity3d**, and also found a way to sign with the old .P12 and the playstore console lets us upload and everything.

**Now to the real question:** The last and current hurdle we have to overcome is find a way to preserve the current users' save games when they update to the Unity version. We use a **SharedObject** to store all user preferences and progress.

I have searched forums, here in SO and in the Unity3D forums and found no one asking a similar question.

But we would like to know if someone knows a way for another app, **with the same signature and packagename** (is basically an update to the AdobeAir app) to read the **SharedObject** from the **AdobeAir** App and parse it so it can create a local save with **Unity3D** (with PlayerPrefs or any other method).

The code we use to Save and Load progress from a **SharedObject** is this:

```
    public function LoadVal(_id:String, _defaultValue:Object = null):Object
    {
        if (existSO(_id)) 
        {
            return loadSO(_id);
        }
        else {
            return _defaultValue;
        }
    }

    private function loadSO(id:String):Object
    {
        mySO = SharedObject.getLocal(nameSO);
        return mySO.data[id];
    }

    public function existSO(id:String):Boolean
    {
        mySO = SharedObject.getLocal(nameSO);
        return mySO.data[id] != null;
    }

    public function SaveVal(id:String,val:Object):void
    {
        mySO = SharedObject.getLocal(nameSO);
        mySO.data[id] = val;
        mySO.flush()
    }

    public function clearSO():void
    {
        mySO = SharedObject.getLocal(nameSO);
        mySO.clear();
    }
```

Comment: First. **SharedObject** has a certain data format (I think it was **AMF3** but not sure), so you can unpack it if you can read it. Then, if you publish an application update, it probably can read everything the original app can. But, the more sure and less technically difficult way is to publish an update to current app that either copies the data to some common format (like JSON or XML) into some common folder (like File.applicationStorageDirectory) or transfer data saves to your own server.